# Ordenar textos por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo una secuencia de párrafos y me gustaría ordenarlos, primero que todo tengo que formar el array para luego ejecutar el sort, me pueden ayudar, hare un esquema del ejemplo:

```
<div class="texto">
    <p>Textoy</p>
</div>
<div class="texto">
    <p>Textoh</p>
</div>
<div class="texto">
    <p>Textoa</p>
</div>
<div class="texto">
    <p>Textop</p>
</div>
<div class="texto">
    <p>Textor</p>
</div>
```

Me apoyan que por medio de javascript se puedan ordenar los textos de las etqueta

por medio de un botton por ejemplo

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Esos elementos ya existen o deben crearse dinámicamente? Sea como sea, ¿qué has intentado y qué problemas o errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Obtener el array es tan sencillo como `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.texto p'))`... luego puedes ordenar con `.sort`